# В старых браузерах неправильно отображает css3 - как поправить?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть цитата с маленьким треугольничком внизу, для указания источника цитаты. В новых браузерах все отображается корректно

[image: уголок в хроме]

А в старых - вот так.

[image: уголок в мозилле]

Как это можно поправить? Сам код ниже

```css
.qvs-testimonial {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.qvs-testimonial-quote {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.qvs-testimonial-quote:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 40px;
}
.qvs-testimonial-quote p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="qvs-testimonial-quote">
  <p>Lorem ipsum ex vix illud nonummy, novum tation et his. At vix scriptaset patrioque scribentur, at pro fugit erts verterem molestiae, sed et vivendo ali Lorem ipsum ex vix illud nonummy, novum tation et his.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: укажите, в каких именно браузерах наблюдаются указанные проблемы?

Comment: Старые браузеры - это какие? В IE9 работает. Чем обусловлена необхдимость поддерживать IE8 и ниже?

Comment: в мозилле 16. возможно, что это особенность исключительно firefox

Comment: используйте тогда уголок изображение

Comment: а кодом как это записать? например, кокретно для мозилы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/j7tjqsL9/
html

```
<div class="qvs-testimonial-quote">
  <p>Lorem ipsum ex vix illud nonummy, novum tation et his. At vix scriptaset patrioque scribentur, at pro fugit erts verterem molestiae, sed et vivendo ali Lorem ipsum ex vix illud nonummy, novum tation et his.</p>
</div>
```

css

```
.qvs-testimonial {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.qvs-testimonial-quote {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.qvs-testimonial-quote:after, .qvs-testimonial-quote:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 40px;
}
.qvs-testimonial-quote:before {
  border-left-color: #999;
  bottom: -21px;
}
.qvs-testimonial-quote p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Для firefox доавится border-color: rgba(241,241,241,.01); https://jsfiddle.net/j7tjqsL9/1/